# WKWebView in UITableViewCell disappearing content

Tags: swift, uitableview, webview, wkwebview

I'm trying to setup a TableView to display my content as follows:
1 [HEADING PHOTO]
2. Content from URL
3. Related items from Json
4. [FOOTER]

Cell 1 is working properly, for cell 2 I have a dynamic height, which gets updated once the content is reloaded. However, if my content (and also the cell) is bigger than my screen it's not show. Only on a zoom gesture the text appears. I can scroll, down, since the Cell and WebView are the proper size. When I scroll back to the top, I the text outside my screen is being cut off again, and appears on zoom gesture.

This is my webview being loaded into my cell

```
class ArticleDetailPost: UITableViewCell, WKNavigationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var articleDetailController = ArticleDetailController(style: .grouped)
    var indexPath: IndexPath?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var article: Article? {
        didSet {
            if let bind_id = article?.bind_id {
                webView.navigationDelegate = self
                webView.scrollView.delegate = self
                let base = URL(string: "http://dev.cubrass.nl/app.php?article_id="+bind_id)
                let url = URLRequest(url: base!)
                webView.load(url)
            }
        }
    }

    let webView: WKWebView = {
       let wv = WKWebView()
        wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wv.isOpaque = false
        wv.backgroundColor = .clear
        wv.scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        wv.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        wv.scrollView.bounces = false
        wv.alpha = 0.0
        return wv
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(webView)
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil;
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if webView.isLoading == false {

            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { [weak self] (result, error) in
                if let height = result as? CGFloat {

                    let newHeight = height + 200
                    webView.frame.size.height += newHeight

                    print("scrollheight ",webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
                    print(ArticleDetailController.contentHeights[(self?.indexPath?.row)!])

                    if (ArticleDetailController.contentHeights[(self?.indexPath?.row)!] != 0.0 &&
                            ArticleDetailController.contentHeights[(self?.indexPath?.row)!] == newHeight
                        )
                    {
                        webView.alpha = 1.0
                        return
                    }
                    let indexPath = self?.indexPath
                    ArticleDetailController.contentHeights[(self?.indexPath?.row)!] = newHeight

                    self?.articleDetailController.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ArticleDetailPost
    cell.article = article
    cell.articleDetailController = self
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell
}
```

Looking for a solution that solves the problem and I can just scroll the tableview and see all the content inside the webview without having it to render with a zoom gesture.